# Python not validating my variable

Tags: python, validation

```
 print("What is your name?") 
 Name = input().title() 
 Class = str(input ("What class are you in? "))
 while Class != "1" and Class != "2" and Class != "3":
```

I want python to say that no name has been in putted by checking something has been entered.

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: `while not Class: Class = input("Try again: ")`

Comment: `while` should be on top, not bottom. And the rest must be indented.

Comment: See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/4014959) for further techniques.

Answer (score 1):

use a list of options

```
options = ['1', '2', '3']

while True:
    Class = input('Please enter your class')
    if Class not in options:
        # try again
        continue
    else:
        break
```